# Python \n newline through Variable Posts \n instead of a new line

Tags: python, variables, python-requests, newline

**My code gets the Content of the Message like so (works fine):**

```
try:
    s, message=nachricht.split("'content': '")
    message, s=message.split("', 'channel_id'")
except:
    message="."
```

**Now in the Result we get a Variable like this:**
*Hello i\nam\nDeployd*
**or**
*Hello i
am
Deployd.*

**This is the Second part it uses the Variable to post it to Discord:**

```
payload=json.dumps({
```

**"content": f"{message}\n{attachments}"**

```
, "username": f"{user_name}#{user_discrm}, {user_id}{namehookidentifiyer}", "avatar_url": f"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/{user_id}/{avatar_code}.png?size=4096"})
req = requests.post(f"{webhook}", data=payload.encode(),headers=headers)
while req.status_code==429:
     time.sleep(1)
     req = requests.post(f"{webhook}", data=payload.encode(), headers=headers)*
```

We only care about the content Variable right here so if as shown the content=
**f"{message}\n{attachments}"**
the \n used in the Middle works just like it should.
But the \n of the message Variable works like it is `\\n` not \n so the outcome is:

```
message \n variable

attachments variable
```

i want that \n to be a new line, i hope you understood everything please help me.

`-------------------------------------------`

I tried to not use the {message} instead only use content=message
that got the same outcome (with the \n being displayed)

How you may have read if the \n is defined in the content: "\n" without a variable it works fine so its not like \n cant work

I also printed the Varables after they were made and after send to discord
it always was \n not `\\n` so it technically should have worked

Also the attachments Variable also has \n newlines and that works even though its a Variable used just like the content one i think thats because the \n inside the attachments variable is defined in the String not from outside:

```
attachments=f"{attachments}\n{value}"
```

The \n's from the content are split out of the output of a file:

```
datei = open(f'./data/{guildname}/{kategorie}/{channelname}.txt','r')
nachrichten=datei.read()
for nachricht in nachrichten:
   if len(nachricht)>=10:
       try:
          s, message=nachricht.split("'content': '")
          message, s=message.split("', 'channel_id'")
       except:
          message="."
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed it by adding this code:**

```
s, message1=nachricht.split("'content': '")
message1, s=message1.split("', 'channel_id'")
message=""
for value in message1.split('\\n'):
    message=f"{message}\n{value}"
```

Chanched the massage Variable to massage1
then splitting it on every \n and putting the split parts together but with a \n inside the message=**"\n"** so its not from an outside variable, i figured this out by looking at the attachments because they worked fine, then i though of a solution to bring the \n outside a variable into the code.